# Altered signal intensity lesion in frontal horn of right lateral ventricle in subependymal region without post contrast enhancement

Tags: brain, mri

There is evidence of approximately 9*8 mm sized altered signal intensity lesion is noted in frontal horn of right lateral ventricle in subependymal region.

Lesion appears hypointense on T1W, hyperintense on T2W / FLAIR images and not showing restrictions of diffusion on DWI. Lesion does not show post contrast enhancement.

> This is MRI report, what does this mean ?

Comment: The physician who ordered it should interpret it for the patient.  Sometimes they will consult additional specialists to investigate further if necessary.  We cannot diagnose or recommend here.

Comment: Yes but what does report says ? Can you please elaborate, because all I understand from Google is that it's tumer.. ps. I don't have medical background.

Comment: TW1 TW2 FLAIR DWI and contrast are MRI imaging modalities that help characterize properties of a mass.  They are too technical to fully understand without a medical background - it would take chapters to explain the principles of tissue imaging, and wouldn't help much. Because there is limited utility of an MRI without clinical correlate.  But if you add the clinical correlate for the patient, you've already sort of hinted that this is someone you know and you're looking for a diagnosis and treatment, so it doesn't meet site guidelines.

Comment: Hence why the ordering physician who knows the clinical history and physical exam needs to be the one to explain it, in order to get the answers you were looking for.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_MRI#Diffusion_imaging